# Why the variable column in this case is 3?

Tags: php, for-loop

it is about a for loop problem

```
for ($row = 1; $row <= $highestRow; $row++) {
    echo "<tr>";
    for ($column = 0; $column < $highestColumn; $column++) {
        $val = $sheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($column, $row)->getValue();
        echo "<td>";
        //echo $val;
        echo $row,$column;
        echo "</td>";
  }
  echo "</tr>";
}
```

the highest row and highestcolumn are both are 4 in this case
OUTPUT:

```
test.xlsx

Import from spreadsheet files

Unname coloum 0  Unname coloum 1  Unname coloum 2  Unname coloum 3  
    13                   13               13                13
    23                   23               23                23
    33                   33               33                33
    43                   43               43                43
```

the value of column is 3 and never change( it should at least be 0?) , i haven't initialize it before, it is strange

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../plugin/easyui/themes/default/easyui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../plugin/easyui/themes/icon.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../style/form1.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../plugin/easyui/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../plugin/easyui/jquery.easyui.min.js"></script>
    </script>
</head>
<body>


<?
session_start();

$file=$_POST['excel'];

include '../plugin/excel/Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';
$reader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel2007');
$PHPExcel = $reader->load($file);
$sheet = $PHPExcel->getSheet(0);
$highestRow = $sheet->getHighestRow();
$highestColumn = PHPExcel_Cell::columnIndexFromString($sheet->getHighestColumn());
?>
<div id="stylized" class="view">
<h1><?echo $file;?></h1> 
<p>Import from spreadsheet files</p>
<table id="tt" class="easyui-datagrid" style="width:auto;height:auto;" >
<thead>
<tr>
<?
for ($head = 0; $head < $highestColumn; $head++){
echo "<th field='col' $head> Unname coloum $head </th>";
}
?></tr>
</thead>
<tbody>

<?

for ($row = 1; $row <= $highestRow; $row++) {
    echo "<tr>";
    for ($column = 0; $column < $highestColumn; $column++) {
    $val = $sheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($column, $row)->getValue();
    echo "<td>";
    //echo $val;
    echo "$row,$column";
    echo "</td>";
  }
  echo "</tr>";
}


?>
</tbody>
</table>
<div class="spacer"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

thanks

Comment: Can you please indent your code properly? And at least start your sentences with a capital?

Comment: sorry about that i was hurry to post it.

Comment: It's not his fault SO hates the tab character :)

Comment: I dont see any errors in this code, I don't think it's possible. Maybe you have misspelled something. Try to initialize the variable before the loop, but I don't think that'll help.

Comment: If `$highestRow` is 4 and `$row` starts at 1, how are you getting four rows?  Please post actual code and actual output.

Comment: @Tim True. But SO doesn't hate capital letters ;)

Comment: I also can not see any errors in the code that get you always print a 3. Running your code without $sheet->getCellByColumnAndRow works also fine. What happens if you comment that call out? Maybe you can also provide more code?

Comment: @user782104 What is `$sheet` an instance of?

Comment: That highest row should be 4 (start from 1 to highest equal to 4) , any problem?

Comment: I would say `getCellByColumnAndRow` gets `$column` by reference and alters it... Could you try to output it _before_ that call?

Comment: this is all of the code, i am using phpExcel to read
it works with table markup, so i believe there is something incorrect about table?? thanks again for your kindly help

Comment: Now, post your actual output...

Comment: try commenting out the ` $val = $sheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($column, $row)->getValue();` and see what happens

Comment: @Wrikken - not unless it's a customised version of PHPExcel, there's no pass by reference in that method call

Comment: Hm, not by reference in the phpExcel version I downloaded in any case....

Comment: it works if i cancel out all table markup td, tr, table...
coz i use it with jquery easyui ,is it possible clashed with it?

Comment: What happens if you change your variable name from `$column` to something else, maybe `$x`?

Comment: If it works when you remove the table markup, it is more likely to be something with jquery.easyui – does it also display the data correctly if you remove jquery.easyui.min.js?

Comment: Also, I see a lot of inconsistency in what you say your code is, and what you show the output to be.  Are you using `echo "$row,$column";` or `echo $row,$column;`, or something else entirely?

Comment: Can we clean up some of the comment?  You guys are straying *so* far away from the post and we'd like to keep the post relevant.

Comment: thats the jquery easyui problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Too big for a comment:

Try changing

```
$highestRow = $sheet->getHighestRow(); 
$highestColumn = PHPExcel_Cell::columnIndexFromString($sheet->getHighestColumn());
```

to

```
$highestRow = $sheet->getHighestRow(); 
$highestColumn = $sheet->getHighestColumn(); 
$highestColumn++;
```

and

```
for ($head = 0; $head < $highestColumn; $head++){  
    echo "<th field='col' $head> Unname coloum $head </th>";  
}
```

to

```
for ($head = 'A'; $head !== $highestColumn; $head++){  
    echo "<th field='col' $head> Unname coloum $head </th>";  
}
```

and

```
for ($column = 0; $column < $highestColumn; $column++) {        
    $val = $sheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($column, $row)->getValue();        
    echo "<td>";        
    //echo $val;        
    echo "$row,$column";        
    echo "</td>";        
}
```

to

```
for ($column = 'A'; $column !== $highestColumn; $column++) {     
    // $val = $sheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($column, $row)->getValue();     
    echo "<td>";     
    //echo $val;     
    echo $row , $column;     
    echo "</td>";     
}
```

Note that I've commented out the getCell call for the moment